# Pandas assert_frame_equal error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm building test cases and I want to compare 2 dataframes.
Even though dataframe have the same columns and values assert_frame_equal reports are not equal.
Column order is different, I tried reordering columns without any success.

In my test case Im using the following function:

```
testing.assert_frame_equal(expected, tested, check_dtype=False)
```

The first dataframe is declared like this:

```
    df2 = pandas.DataFrame({
    'artista': [u'Beyoncé', 'Radiolab', 'Xmas', 'Beyonce'],
    'mid_sugerido': ['/g/11bz0dg4b_', '/g/11bt_6j9dk', '/g/11c2nz8jc2', '/g/11bt_6jXXX'],
    'texto': ['Lemonade', 'Radiolab', 'Merry Christmas Lil Mama', 'Beyonce'],
    'busqueda': [u'Beyoncé', 'Radiolab', 'Xmas', 'Beyonce'],
    'texto_sugerido': ['Lemonade', 'Radiolab', 'Merry Christmas Lil Mama', 'Beyonce'],
    'artista_sugerido': [u'Beyoncé', 'Radiolab', None, 'Beyonce'],
    'media_sugerido': ['album', 'album', 'track', 'album'],

})
```

Pandas dataframe pd2:

```
    artista artista_sugerido  busqueda media_sugerido   mid_sugerido  \
0   Beyoncé          Beyoncé   Beyoncé          album  /g/11bz0dg4b_   
1  Radiolab         Radiolab  Radiolab          album  /g/11bt_6j9dk   
2      Xmas             None      Xmas          track  /g/11c2nz8jc2   
3   Beyonce          Beyonce   Beyonce          album  /g/11bt_6jXXX   

                      texto            texto_sugerido  
0                  Lemonade                  Lemonade  
1                  Radiolab                  Radiolab  
2  Merry Christmas Lil Mama  Merry Christmas Lil Mama  
3                   Beyonce                   Beyonce
```

The second dataframe is the dataframe returned from function (result).

```
    artista  busqueda   mid_sugerido                     texto  \
0   Beyoncé   Beyoncé  /g/11bz0dg4b_                  Lemonade   
1  Radiolab  Radiolab  /g/11bt_6j9dk                  Radiolab   
2      Xmas      Xmas  /g/11c2nz8jc2  Merry Christmas Lil Mama   
3   Beyonce   Beyonce  /g/11bt_6jXXX                   Beyonce   

             texto_sugerido artista_sugerido media_sugerido  
0                  Lemonade          Beyoncé          album  
1                  Radiolab         Radiolab          album  
2  Merry Christmas Lil Mama             None          track  
3                   Beyonce          Beyonce          album
```

I get the following error when i run: `assert_frame_equal(df2, result)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/Development/parzee/python/coverage/experimental/pandas_creation.py", line 158, in <module>
    assert_frame_equal(df6, _Normalize(df5, test_dict))
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/Development/parzee/python/coverage/experimental/pandas_creation.py", line 16, in assert_frame_equal
    testing.assert_frame_equal(expected, tested, check_dtype=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/testing.py", line 1142, in assert_frame_equal
    obj='{0}.columns'.format(obj))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/testing.py", line 761, in assert_index_equal
    obj=obj, lobj=left, robj=right)
  File "pandas/src/testing.pyx", line 58, in pandas._testing.assert_almost_equal (pandas/src/testing.c:3887)
  File "pandas/src/testing.pyx", line 147, in pandas._testing.assert_almost_equal (pandas/src/testing.c:2769)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/testing.py", line 915, in raise_assert_detail
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: DataFrame.columns are different

DataFrame.columns values are different (85.71429 %)
[left]:  Index([u'artista', u'artista_sugerido', u'busqueda', u'media_sugerido',
       u'mid_sugerido', u'texto', u'texto_sugerido'],
      dtype='object')
[right]: Index([u'artista', u'busqueda', u'mid_sugerido', u'texto', u'texto_sugerido',
       u'artista_sugerido', u'media_sugerido'],
      dtype='object')
```

Columns are the same, but different order, If I use df.sort_index(axis=1) to reorder columns I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/Development/parzee/python/coverage/experimental/pandas_creation.py", line 154, in <module>
    assert_frame_equal(df6.sort_index(axis=1), _Normalize(df5, test_dict).sort_index(axis=1))
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/Development/parzee/python/coverage/experimental/pandas_creation.py", line 16, in assert_frame_equal
    testing.assert_frame_equal(expected, tested, check_dtype=False, check_like=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/testing.py", line 1166, in assert_frame_equal
    obj='DataFrame.iloc[:, {0}]'.format(i))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/testing.py", line 1049, in assert_series_equal
    check_less_precise, obj='{0}'.format(obj))
  File "pandas/src/testing.pyx", line 58, in pandas._testing.assert_almost_equal (pandas/src/testing.c:3887)
  File "pandas/src/testing.pyx", line 147, in pandas._testing.assert_almost_equal (pandas/src/testing.c:2769)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/testing.py", line 914, in raise_assert_detail
    [right]: {3}""".format(obj, message, left, right)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by replacing:

```
assert_frame_equal(df2.sort_index(axis=1), myfunction(df1).sort_index(axis=1))
```

with

```
l  = myfunction(df1)
assert_frame_equal(df2.sort_index(axis=1), l.sort_index(axis=1))
```

Comment: Why is there any difference between those two approaches? Shouldn't they yield the same result?

Comment: I think so, I still dont understand why it works, will debug further.

Comment: @gogasca Have you figured out the difference? Would love an update on this.

Comment: oh, that was long time ago. Never really dig further, sorry about it

Comment: Both versions here are the exact same thing, this probably looked like it fixed it, but something else has to have been the real solution. Marking this as the accepted answer is confusing.

Comment: Had the same issue, had something to do my left.columns.names == right.columns.names being False, no clue why it was the case though.