# assert_frame_equal asserting for two same pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am doing 2 pandas dataframe comparison and this is where my assertion is failing.

`pd.testing.assert_frame_equal`

This is the assertion error

```
E   AssertionError: DataFrame.iloc[:, 8] (column name="xxxxx") are different
E
E   DataFrame.iloc[:, 8] (column name="xxxxx") values are different (50.0 %)
E   [left]:  [143455434, None]
E   [right]: [143455434, None]
```

Both left and right are same still it is giving error. Both columns are object types

Comment: I can't help, but I'm getting the same. Perhaps a bug. If I use df1.equals(df2) I get equality, and similarly when I use assert_series_equal on the apparently offending column I get equality too. I did use this answer to help one of my cases pass: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088121/pandas-assert-frame-equal-error

Comment: Strangely I converted them to str and it worked. Could possibly a bug

Comment: Yep, same here, if I convert to string I get equality.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In the end, I used the option `check_dtype=False` from `assert_frame_equal`, and the assert works.

... types, who need them?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a bug. Workaround is to convert to str and then check